# Same codes but charset dont work on index.php

Tags: php, html

i have an interesting problem on index.php page. I have pages with complately same codes (tried copying all other pages to try on index.php as well) but on index.php, Turkish characters are not showing properly. Even with the complately same codes. What can cause that? Only index.php showing wrong.

Tried same codes but maybe you want to check my head tag.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-5.0.0-beta2-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="bootstrap-5.0.0-beta2-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="tr">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<title>title</title>
<meta name="description" content="deneme">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

I created a new empty file in Brackets. Then copied old index.php to new one, now working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must see settings of you webserver? For example .htaccess or /etc/apache2/apache2.conf...

And check: Do you using header() or no before "html block" in index.php...

[image: screeshot]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3FB2.png

Comment: I have this problem on both local server and live web server. Yes, my blocks looks like this photo. As i said when i copy  all the working page to index, TR charset not working anymore. index works different but i dont get it.

Comment: How exactly does the tongue break? Turkish special letters not displayed? Or does the entire text become unreadable? What encoding is the index.php file saved in?

Comment: You can see my index here : http://bilgisayarsec.site/

Comment: This is not  "index.php" file, This is the result of .php file interpretation. In what encoding (utf-8 or not?) is the "index.php" stored on the server? And in what encoding is the text copied into it?

Comment: utf8. Yes the index php is stored on server. You can click the orange button in the middle to change page. There, you can see page1 works without any problem. http://bilgisayarsec.site/page1.php?

Comment: When you copy the text to the index.php, in the file itself, when viewed by an editor (for example, vim, nano, vsсode) is the text displayed correctly? or also squares?
Was the text for the index.php file originally typed in notepad in ANSI encoding? When copying from there, information about national fonts may be lost...  Maybe someone copied / saved the original Windows1254 encoding to UTF-8 without conversion ... (https://i.postimg.cc/HkZxBSs7/1.png)
(https://i.postimg.cc/LsGsMnP9/2.png)
(https://i.postimg.cc/CKRKtjzr/3.png)
(https://i.postimg.cc/1XQ5f2Mb/4.png)